# Calendar in Android app to select month and year

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, calendar, widget

I want to have a calendar that would allow the user to only choose month and year. Are there any 3rd party widgets that would allow me to do that? I know about date slider (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDFls.png) that allows me to create a dialog box where user would choose month and year, but is there a widget that is similar to what I posted below? Or would I have to create this myself?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [CalDroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid). It has customization options to allow you to create the desired effect.

Edit: Read the documentation on the project's GitHub:

> Caldroid fragment includes 4 main parts:
>
> 1) Month title view: show the month and year (e.g MARCH, 2013)
>
> 2) Navigation arrows: to navigate to next month or previous month
>
> 3) Weekday gridview: contains only 1 row and 7 columns. To display "SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT"
>
> 4) An infinite view pager that allow user to swipe left/right to change month. This library is taken from https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Number (1) seems to be what you need.

Comment: Could you write some code to show me how I would customize the calendar so that it shows only months and years?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you think they meant that it's possible to get month and a year that user selected from a regular calendar in "MONTH YYYY" format, rather than have a calendar that looks like the one in my screenshot?

Comment: Is this library still reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for this reasonably simple use case, I'd not bother with some 3rd-party thing you can't easily debug/maintain. I'd use two ViewFlippers -- one for month and one for day. `ViewFlipper` supports animation, so you can get some nice looking physics to it when the user spins to a month/day.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is, [Calendar Times Square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) provides to you a calendar to display and then a way to choose from it some date:

first, import the calendar into your project.

then, display it the following way:

```
        //get the current date:
        Calendar firstYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        firstYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
        lastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);

        // to declare the calendar with the current date and make it scrollable for a past year and an upcoming year
        final CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
        calendar.init(firstYear.getTime() , lastYear.getTime())
            .withSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

then, when want to save the selected date:

```
    Date new_date = calendar.getSelectedDate();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new_date);

    // to make sure it saved to the system
    if (ShellInterface.isSuAvailable()) {
          ShellInterface.runCommand("chmod 666 /dev/alarm");
          SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
          ShellInterface.runCommand("chmod 664 /dev/alarm");
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to customize this calendar so that it shows month and year (as my screenshot) instead of date, month and year?

Comment: No, it will display day also, I thought you are taking about taking the month and year from it(it allows that), but when coming to how it will be displayed it will display the calendar like system calendars(with day also), but despite that it's easy to be customized so you could customize it's code to get what you want.